# AWS Elasticsearch service continually gives 'User anonymous' error

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to my ES cluster from an EC2 instance and have configured my IAM policy to accept requests from my key/secret pair.  I'm using ruby to try a query on the service and keep getting a 403 'User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet on resource: arn...'

My code looks like so:

```
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'https://myEScluster.es.amazonaws.com' do |f|
  f.request :aws_signers_v4,
        credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('mykey', 'mysecret'),
        service_name: 'es',
        region: 'us-east-1'
end
```

I get the error when i try to do a client.search.  I've looked through all of the github issues and documentation for the ES gem, which say to do what I am trying:
"You can use any standard Faraday middleware and plugins in the configuration block, for example sign the requests for the AWS Elasticsearch service:"

```
require 'patron'
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'https://search-my-cluster-abc123....es.amazonaws.com' do |f|
  f.request :aws_signers_v4,
            credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
            service_name: 'es',
            region: 'us-east-1'
end
```

As you can see, it's pretty much the same.  I also tried these:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/232

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/pull/235

One other thing, here is my ES service security policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "myarn"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "myresourcearn/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, Amazon's documentation on this is lacking and their services api only offers basic maintenance functions.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your elasticsearch gem version, i was using 1.0.14 and getting the same error. Bumping to 1.0.15 fixed allows the block to configure the  transport to use signed requests. See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1015.

Comment: that was exactly it.  I should really learn to update my gems. Thanks for the help!